# Running multiple commands in bash and creating new directories and moving csv files into the new directory

Tags: bash, file, pcap

I have several pcap files on which I would like to apply the same commands on (these are Argus commands a network flow tool)

- Convert the PCAP file to an argus file
- Run four Argus commands that outputs 4 .csv files
- Create a new directory based on the .pcap file name but with only the first part of the pcap name e.g amazonecho_merge I didnt want the merge part as part of the new directory name
- Place all new .csv files into the new directory

  ```
    for file in *.pcap
     do
     argus -r *.pcap -w packet.argus
    #Run argus to get the flow volumn (totalbytes) and the flow duration      (seconds)
     ra -r packet.argus -s bytes dur > flow_vol_dur.csv
    #Run argus to get the source and destination ports, merge both    columns together and count how many occurances
     racluster -r packet.argus -n -s sport dport > ports.csv
     ra -r packet.argus -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 53 >   DNS.csv
     ra -r packet.argus -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 123 >   NTP.csv
     dir=$(echo ${file} | awk -F. '{print $1}' OFS=.)
     mkdir $dir
    #Move all newly created .csv files to the new directory 
     mv $file*.csv $dir
    done
  ```

I think naming the new directory is incorrect as I only want part of the name of the pcap file

I am sure there is a better way of running the commands especially this one

```
  ra -r packet.argus -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 53 >   DNS.csv 
  ra -r packet.argus -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 123 >   NTP.csv
```

when there is only slight change in the command I would like to know if there is a easier format of running these commands

Is there a way in bash to merge the columns from the different csv files into single csv file

```
e.g 

      file1.csv

      A,B

      file2.csv

      C,D

      Desired output.csv

      A,B,C,D
```

I have tried join and does not work is there any other bash command that will work?

Comment: if you don't want the second part of the file name in the dir name        use:
dir=$(echo $file| awk -F_  '{print $1}')

Comment: @Tina hi, could you make clear what your question is?

Comment: @suspectus Hi could you tell me what is unclear or missing from the question.  I have 12 pcap files and I would like to run several Argus commands as well as create a new directory and the newly created output files from Argus (.csv files) into the new directories

Comment: @Tina it's just that there isn't a question in the post. What isn't working from your work so far?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most of your commands don't need to run once per file, so if you change the order you can save some runtime:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

argus -r *.pcap -w packet.argus

# Run argus to get the flow volumn (totalbytes) and the flow duration      (seconds)
ra -r packet.argus -s bytes dur > flow_vol_dur.csv

# Run argus to get the source and destination ports, merge both columns together and count how many occurances
racluster -r packet.argus -n -s sport dport > ports.csv
ra -r packet.argus -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 53 > DNS.csv
ra -r packet.argus -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 123 > NTP.csv

for file in *.pcap
    do
    dir=$(echo $file| awk -F_ '{print $1}')
    mkdir $dir
    # Move all newly created .csv files to the new directory 
    mv $file*.csv $dir
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have like 12 pcap files if i wanted to run the Argus commands on each file wouldnt i need to put in the for loop

Comment: Since this is bash, you only need `dir=${file%_*}` to get, e.g. `amazonecho` from `amazonecho_merge`. (which saves spawning 4-subshells needed for `$(echo $file| awk -F_ '{print $1}')`)

Comment: Your third line runs on all your pcap files, not one at a time.